# MySqlBulkLoader is not importing first column

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a very simple csv file with two columns that I need to import into MySQl. The table has the same columns with same names. When I run the below code, the first column gets imported as 0 and the second column imports the correct values.

C# Code:

```
MySqlBulkLoader bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn)
                {
                    TableName = "tableName",
                    FieldTerminator = ",",
                    LineTerminator = "\r",
                    FileName = fileName,
                    NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1,
                    Timeout = 0
                };
bl.Load();
```

CSV:

```
product_id,qty
35373,155
35374,169
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `qty` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The LineTerminator had to be set to \r\n.